# Http delete gets bad request in Android

Tags: android, http

I am working with Android http stuff to register/unregister to the server. I have a DELETE request to use HttpDelete. I am getting Http401 'Bad request' error when I try to call it. I cannot why it is happening. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
HttpUtils.java

private BasicHttpParams mParams;
private UsernamePasswordCredentials mCredentials = null;
private ResponseHandler mResponseHandler = null;

public void setUserCredentials(String userName, String password) {
     this.mCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password);
}

public void setResponseHandler(ResponseHandler responseHandler){
    this.mResponseHandler = responseHandler;
}

public Result<String> delete(String url){
    Result<String> result = new Result<T>();
    result.setStatus(Result.FAIL);

        try {
         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mParams);
         httpClient.setParams(mParams);
         httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1), mCredentials);

         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpDelete(url));
         result.setResult(mResponseHandler.handleResponse(response));
         result.setStatus(Result.SUCCESS);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
          result.setMessage("Connection timed out.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    } 

    return result;
}

UnregisterTask.java
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        if (urls==null || urls.length!=1)
            return null;

        String url = urls[0];

                HttpUtils httpUtils = new HttpUtils();
                httpUtils.setUserCredentials("userid", "password");
                httpUtils.setResponseHandler(new UnrgisterHandler());
        httpUtils.delete(url);

        Result<String> result = aClient.delete(url);
        if (result!=null || result.result != null){
                     //Do Something
                 }

    }


//UnrgisterActivity.java

public void onUnregisterButtonClick(View view){
     UnregisterTask task = new UnregisterTask(this);
     task.execute(ServerConfig.getIdmServer() + ServerConfig.DELETE_DEVICE + "myid");
}
```

Error recevied:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you give INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Sure, I did. Get, put and post are working well.

Comment: can you upload the error log in question please ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by myself but I do not understand clearly why the error happened. I changed my code after searching how to set basic authentication.

```
public Result<T> delete(String url)

        Result<T> result = new Result<T>();
        result.setStatus(Status.FAIL);

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();

            if (this.mCredentials!=null){
                CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), this.mCredentials);
                http.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
            }

            HttpDelete delete = new HttpDelete(url);
            //delete.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, "UTF8"));
            delete.addHeader("Content-type", JSON_TYPE);
            HttpResponse response = http.execute(delete);
            result.setResult(mResponseHandler.handleResponse(response));
            result.setStatus(Result.Status.SUCCESS);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            result.setMessage("Connection timed out.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        } 

        return result;
    }
```

A bit still confusing. Anyway, now it works charm.